# suggest value form input HTMl JS

Tags: javascript, html

i want to type in input auto suggest value in form

[image]

```
   <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
         <input type="text" class="form-control valid" name="enddate" id="enddate" value="<?php echo $enddate; ?>">
         <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
   </div>
```

Comment: Where from do you want to get values ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script>
         $(function() {
            var availableTutorials = [
               "ActionScript",
               "Boostrap",
               "Candsomething",
               "ActionScript",
               "Boostrap",
               "Carwith other car",
               "dwithsometext",
            ];
            $( "#automplete-1" ).autocomplete({
               source: availableTutorials
            });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <!-- HTML --> 
      <div class="ui-widget">
         <p>Type "a" or "c"</p>
         <label for="automplete-1">Tags: </label>
         <input id="automplete-1">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

if you are working with php and mysql then check this link   http://www.bewebdeveloper.com/tutorial-about-autocomplete-using-php-mysql-and-jquery

Comment: Thanks U @@ i just try it. and ok